# Angular 2 throws 'cssText.replace is not a function' when using ExtractTextPlugin

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-style-loader, extract-text-plugin

I have two projects: `Project A` and `Project B`.

Project A

1. Webpack@2.2.1
2. Extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.0.0-rc.3
3. Angular 2.4.3

Project B

1. Angular 2.4.3

`Project B` provides a series of modules/components to `Project A`.

The code is compiled (not bundled) by `Project B` into a dist folder which then is being used by `Project A` via `npm link`.

Right now, with the `webpack.common.js` settings using the `ExtractTextPlugin` the browsers throws an Exception: 
[image: screen shot 2017-02-09 at 12 29 03 pm]

This exception is being thrown by Angular 2, but **only** when this plugin is used.
I am saying this, because if I load `.css` extensions using `raw-loader` everything works fine, but when using ExtractTextPlugin, it just breaks.

### ***VALID***

webpack.config.js

```
module: {
   rules: [
      {
         test: /\.css$/,
         use: [ "raw-loader" ],
      }
   ]
}
```

Output:

[image: screen shot 2017-02-09 at 12 43 14 pm]

### ***INVALID (using ExtractTextPlugin)***

webpack.config.js

```
module: {
   rules: [
      {
         test: /\.css$/,
         use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract( {
                  fallback: "raw-loader",
                  use: [ "raw-loader" ]
         } )
      }
   }
},
plugins: [
   new ExtractTextPlugin( "[name].css" ),
]
```

Output:

[image: screen shot 2017-02-09 at 12 30 20 pm]

Exception thrown:

```
Uncaught TypeError: cssText.replace is not a function
    at extractStyleUrls (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:75001:52)
```

Node: 6.2.0
OS: macOS Sierra (10.12.2)

Comment: See if that helps, worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40935793/webpack-sass-build-issue-everything-compiles-fine-then-i-get-a-js-error

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue because I had a `@Component` `styleUrl` that was referencing a valid stylesheet file but the file was empty.  Removing the unnecessary `styleUrl` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check answer in this [Webpack SASS build issue, everything compiles fine, then I get a JS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40935793/webpack-sass-build-issue-everything-compiles-fine-then-i-get-a-js-error/40937354#40937354)

In addition to the answer you can either use `require` or you can simply `import` those `.css` files on top of your component.ts file.

Like `import '../assets/app.css';`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `"angular2-template-loader":"^0.6.2"` in your `dependencies` in `package.json` then exec `npm i`. This solved my same issue